# Monthly Loan Repayment Formula

Tags: calculus, finance

I need a layman's explanation on how to calculate monthly loan repayments. I don't know algebra.

To calculate the monthly repayment on £3000 with an APR of 7.9% over 10 years I'm doing the following: 3000 * 0.079 * 10 + 3000 / 120 = Monthly repayment of £44.75 & total repayable £5370

When I use an online loan calculator, £3000 with an APR of 7.9% over 10 years has a monthly repayment of £35.85 and total repayable £4297.28

Where am I going wrong with my maths? P.S Maths isn't exactly one of my strong points so a simple idiot proof explanation would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're charging yourself 7.9% interest on the whole 3000, even though you're repaying it steadily throughout the 10 years.

Comment: @DJohnM Post that as an answer.

Comment: So how do I calculate that?

Comment: The thing I've noticed with stack exchange is no one will just provide a simple answer. I'm a web developer. I'm not someone working with maths. I'm someone building a new website for a company that has just started offering credit facilities and they've asked if I could build a calculator for on their site. I'm not an accountant or a banker. I just need someone to say, you're doing it wrong, do it like this 3000 * 0.079.... etc, but everyone wants to gate keep or play maths yoda and downvote. I'll probably never use this maths again in my life. I just need an answer so I can code it.

Comment: @Anon2945 I´ve solved the equation for x like you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle{\tt @Anon2945}$: $\displaystyle\color{red}{\tt java script}$ is $\displaystyle\underline{\it fine}$ !!!.

```
// Filename: js23sep2020.js
// Run as node js23sep2020.js
"use strict";
const c0 = 3000, n = 120, r = 7.9/1200;
const MONTHLYPAYMENT= c0*r/(1.0 - Math.pow(1.0 + r,-n));

console.log("MONTHLY PAYMENT = " + MONTHLYPAYMENT);
```

$\displaystyle\tt \mathrm{MONTHLY\,\,\, PAYMENT} = 36.23995171985522$.

Comment: Nice to see that we both get the same result. Hopefully the OP can accept it yet.

Comment: @callculus Thanks. $\left(\substack{\bullet\quad\bullet \\ \mid \\ \smile}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Usually the calculation is at follows. Two assumptions:

- Monthly constant repayments ($x$)
- Duration: 120 months
- APR: 0.079
- Payments are made at the end of each month.

Then the equation is

$$3000\cdot \left(1+\frac{0.079}{12}\right)^{120}= x\cdot \frac{\left(1+\frac{0.079}{12}\right)^{120}-1}{\frac{0.079}{12}}$$

$$x=3000\cdot \left(1+\frac{0.079}{12}\right)^{120}\cdot \frac{0.079}{ 12\cdot \left( \left(1+\frac{0.079}{12}\right)^{120}-1 \right)}$$

Solve the equation for $x$ (repayment). The calculator gets [$x=36.24$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3000*%281%2B0.079%2F12%29%5E120%3Dx*%28%281%2B0.079%2F12%29%5E120-1%29%2F%280.079%2F12%29)

See the pictures of the parts of the table from [this site](https://www.bankrate.com/calculators/mortgages/loan-calculator.aspx). All numbers can be comprehended. There is no mystery about the numbers.

[Table(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32cKS.jpg), [Table(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlCMc.jpg), [Table(3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Pc1W.jpg) ,[Table(4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkMQP.jpg), [Table(5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqywv.jpg)

---

Example: Interest and principal in march 2021:

- Balance in february 2021: $2916.46$
- Interest in march 2021: $2916.46\cdot   
     \frac{0.079}{12}=19.200...\approx 19.20$
- Principal in march 2021: $36.24-19.20=17.04$

---

In general the payment can be made at the beginning at each month as well. Then the equation is

$$3000\cdot \left(1+\frac{0.079}{12}\right)^{120}= x\cdot \color{blue}{\left(1+\frac{0.079}{12}\right)}\cdot \frac{\left(1+\frac{0.079}{12}\right)^{120}-1}{\frac{0.079}{12}}$$

The calculator gets [$x=36.00$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3000*%281%2B0.079%2F12%29%5E120%3D%281%2B0.079%2F12%29*x*%28%281%2B0.079%2F12%29%5E120-1%29%2F%280.079%2F12%29)

Comment: I´ve solved the equation for $x$ like you wanted.

Comment: 3000*(1+0.079/12)^120=(1+0.079/12)*x*((1+0.079/12)^120-1)/(0.079/12)  - This just gives me errors in javascript

Comment: I´m not an expert in java script. You have to look up somewhere how to input formulas. And use the formula for the solved x, this basic format: 3000*(1+0.079/12)^120*0.079/(12*((1+0.079/12)^(120)-1)) Or copy it from wolfram alpha, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3000*%281%2B0.079%2F12%29%5E120*0.079%2F%2812*%28%281%2B0.079%2F12%29%5E%28120%29-1%29%29) (link)

Comment: 3000*(1+0.079/12)^120*0.079/(12*((1+0.079/12)^(120)-1)) and the formula on wolfram return 3019 in JS

Comment: Have you opened the link?

Comment: Yes. Also the result I need to arrive at is 35.81. That's the figure that will be on the finance agreement so legally the website can't say it will be 36.

Comment: If there are no other conditions then the right answer is 36.24. Why do you think the answer must be 35.81?

Comment: 35.81 is the monthly payment that the bank is stating on the loan agreement. £3000 at 7.9% interest for 120 months. 120 payments of £35.81 - not £36.24

Comment: But this is wrong from the financial mathematics point of view. What you said is just a statement-nothing else.

Comment: Btw, haven´t you posted that the amount of the payments are £35.8**5**?

Comment: *When I use an online loan calculator...* Which calculator have you used?

Comment: Check this two calculators: [calculator 1](https://extloancalculator.com/calculators/free-online-annuity-calculator.html), [calculator 2](https://www.calculatestuff.com/financial/loan-amortization-calculator)

Comment: The calculators that I've used online quote the same monthly repayment of £35.81 over 120 months. Try this calculator https://www.moneysupermarket.com/loans/calculator/ and this https://moneyfacts.co.uk/loans/loan-calculator/. They both give the same number of £35.81 that the bank says on theirs

Comment: I don´t know what have been calculated there. At this [page](https://www.bankrate.com/calculators/mortgages/loan-calculator.aspx) a table can be created. See my edit with link to a picture of that table. Every step can be comprehended.

Comment: Also the following sites provide  tables with the values of all interest,  principals and    payments: [site 1](https://www.banksiteservices.com/calculators/SimpleLoan.html), [site 2](https://financial-calculators.com/loan-calculator), [site 3](https://www.theguardian.com/money/loan-repayment-calculator-interest-rates)